# Kubuntu or Ubuntu with KDE? What's the difference?

Tags: kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Desktop Environments or use different distributions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141015/install-desktop-environments-or-use-different-distributions)

I've been an Ubuntu user for some time but now looking at moving to a KDE desktop and thinking about installing Kubuntu on my newly rebuilt laptop, however I have an Ubuntu One account and use it a great deal.

Therefore am I better off installing Ubuntu (12.10) and simply adding the KDE desktop afterwards?

Comment: If you are just asking about the possibility of using Ubuntu one on Kubuntu, please clarify that. otherwise this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same thing. Any other flavour of the desktop series is just a pre-selected set of packages. So, the same goes for Lubuntu vs Ubuntu, i.e. Ubuntu (Unity) first, LXDE replacing Unity later being the same as installing Lubuntu directly.

Also see this similar, relevant answer in a different discussion:

- [Does 12.04 LXDE have LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/a/237087/88802)

Ubuntu One is just a package (application) which runs fine on other desktop environments too. This is unrelated to the path to get to run KDE on Ubuntu.